# Xamarin.Forms Webview custom renderer para MacOS y WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, macos, webview

Estoy creando una aplicación Xamarin Forms con un Webview que carga una web local (pdfjs) para mostrar PDF.

He hecho custom renderers para UWP, Android e iOS, siguiendo la documentación oficial y están funcionando, pero ahora he añadido soporte para MacOS y WPF y no se como crear custom renderers en ambos (Webview).

No encuentro ningún ejemplo, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? 
Gracias.

Comment: No se si te ayudara, pero en el github de xamarin.forms hay renderers hechos de todas las plataformas, por ejemplo para wpf https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF/Renderers

Comment: Gracias, no lo sabía, están muy bien los ejemplos.